# Setting default ArcGIS Pro Measure Distance value?

Tags: arcgis-pro, default, measurements

How do I set the Measure Distance tool default value to feet instead of Imperial in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Manual might help: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/measure.htm

Answer (score 2):

From the **Project** tab, select **Options.**

In the **Options** window, under the *Project* heading, click **Units**

Expand **Distance Units** and click the radio box beside which measurement option you want to default.

[image]

Comment: nice picture (added).

Comment: I already have that set.  But when I use the Measure tool, the default is Imperial and I have to manually change it to feet every time I want to measure